# Inter font - black style for a few words, but rest in normal weighted bold?

Tags: fonts

The style examples on https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/interregular/ show the most common styles of fonts used in documents. https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Inter shows that an even heavier style `black 900` ("black") is supplied. And if one scrolls down in that "box"/window on https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/inter/doc, it also says

```
Current font styles:
Name    Weight class
Thin    100
Thin Italic     100
[...]
Bold    700
Bold Italic     700
Extra Bold  800
Extra Bold Italic   800
Black   900 <===========================!!
Black Italic    900 <===========================!!
```

I would like to enable that black style for just a few words, e.g. within a macro, maybe with a command similar to `\texttt{asdf}`. Once these few words are typeset, I would like to be able to return to the "normal" bold format when it is called. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the README that pops up at https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/inter/, "The semibold, extrabold and heavy options activate those series as the default bold series." Thus, we see that `\usepackage[extrabold]{inter}` is what is required to make the `\bfseries` font extra bold.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[extrabold]{inter}
\begin{document}
\sffamily ABC vs \textbf{ABC}
\end{document}
```

[image]

To make all the styles simultaneously available, declarations are provided.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{inter}
\begin{document}
\sffamily ABC vs 

\intersemibold ABC \mdseries vs

\textbf{ABC} vs

\interextrabold ABC \mdseries vs

\interheavy ABC \mdseries
\end{document}
```

[image]

For more information, see also inter-samples.tex at https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/inter/doc.

Comment: Thank you. I meant that I would like to use that heavy format for just a few words. Or within a macro, to be specific. The other bold parts, e.g. the headings, shall remain regular bold. Could you speak on that perhaps? :) (I also amended my op to clarify this detail. Sorry.)

Comment: @henry Please see my edit.

Comment: @henry I made an additional edit, when I realized that the macros are undelimited declarations.

Comment: This font is very grotesque!

Comment: Haha... yes. :) Why do you write that? :) But imho it's Google's version of [Neue Haas](https://www.linotype.com/6598/neue-haas-grotesk.html), [San Francisco](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/San_Francisco_(sans-serif_typeface)), [Neue Helvetica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helvetica#Neue_Helvetica_(1983)) and so forth. Also, its x-height is really large.

Comment: @henry I wrote it just to be silly and ironic.  Thanks for the additional info.

Comment: Oh a pun! Well I managed to do one (1) comparison: https://pastebin.com/aHvncwHq I always forget that I don't know the correct values for different font families. So... that was that.

Comment: How *exactly* did you find these commands?

Comment: @henry From the README that appears at https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/inter/.  Some of the info was explicit, other, inferred.

Comment: @henry See also `inter-samples.tex` at https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/inter/doc

Answer (score 0):

Another way to load all the styles of the font is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

% Works with this version of Inter:
% https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/inter
\defaultfontfeatures[Inter]{
  Path=fonts/,
  Extension=.ttf,
  FontFace={ul}{n}{Font={*-Thin-BETA}},
  FontFace={ul}{it}{Font={*-ThinItalic-BETA}},
  FontFace={el}{n}{Font={*-ExtraLight-BETA}},
  FontFace={el}{it}{Font={*-ExtraLightItalic-BETA}},
  FontFace={l}{n}{Font={*-Light-BETA}},
  FontFace={l}{it}{Font={*-LightItalic-BETA}},
  UprightFont=*-Regular,
  ItalicFont=*-Italic,
  FontFace={mb}{n}{Font={*-Medium}},
  FontFace={mb}{it}{Font={*-MediumItalic}},
  FontFace={sb}{n}{Font={*-SemiBold}},
  FontFace={sb}{it}{Font={*-SemiBoldItalic}},
  BoldFont=*-Bold,
  BoldItalicFont=*-BoldItalic,
  FontFace={eb}{n}{Font={*-ExtraBold}},
  FontFace={eb}{it}{Font={*-ExtraBoldItalic}},
  FontFace={ub}{n}{Font={*-Black}},
  FontFace={ub}{sl}{Font={*-Black}, FakeSlant=0.15},
}

\setmainfont{Inter}
\setsansfont{Inter}

% Declare \ulseries, \elseries, etc. here using the following template:
\newcommand\ubseries{\fontseries{ub}\selectfont}
% Define \textul, \textel, etc. here, using the following template:
\DeclareTextFontCommand\textub{\ubseries}

\begin{document}
Inter \textub{Black} versus \textbf{Bold}
\end{document}
```

[image: Inter sample]

One advantage of this is that it will also work with the Black or Ultra Bold weight of all your other font families, if you set them up the same way.

For this setup, I downloaded [this version of Inter](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/inter) into a subdirectory named `fonts`.